# Is there a delegate function in iOS to get notified when a UIViewController is coming back to top?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, modalviewcontroller

I'm somewhat a Swift/iOS newbie but this seems simple. I have a UIViewController and upon some action I am instantiating another modal UIViewController, which at some point I will dismiss. I just need to originating VC to be notified when this happens. Realizing that this could be handled using navigation control, I'm looking for a way to do it modally i.e.

I want to push the modal vc on to the hierarchy:

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailView")
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and when I do this in the modal vc:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I just want the original vc sitting in the background to be notified it's coming back into focus (or top) and be able to execute code.

What am I missing?

Comment: `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @rmaddy My understanding of viewWillAppear is that it only notifies that a view is about to be added to the view hierarchy. In this case, isn't my view already in the hierarchy, just sitting back one in the stack?

Comment: It's also called when it reappears (in most cases).

Comment: @rmaddy I guess this must be one of those cases. viewWillAppear does not get called - at least, if I am implementing correctly. Simply adding an override function and it doesn't execute when the modal vc dismisses. Hmmm

Comment: Is the modal in a popover? That would be one of the cases.

Comment: @rmaddy Per my code sample above, I assume this might be considered a popover. Is there another way to do it in this case?

Comment: Why don't you post a notification when you do the dismiss, and register for it in all VC's ?

Comment: I've never had any issue with `viewWillAppear` when using `present`. Another thought would be to use delegation. EDIT: I just noticed your comment on the posted answer. I'm not talking the same thing - I'm talking about making the "presenting" VC be a delegate of the popover VC.

Comment: After living with the "hacked" solution I posted below for a while, the simple answer to this is that ```ViewWillAppear``` does NOT get called if the modal presentation style is "Over Current Context." After changing the presentation to "Full Screen", the behavior is what I expected all along, and the override in the presenting VC gets called. Just one of those things you learn along the way.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**: the answer here is very simple. A ViewController that is presented modally with a presentation style of "Over Current Context" does not fire `ViewWillAppear` in the presenting VC when it is dismissed. The answer below worked fine as a hack, but the easier solution is what I was looking for. That is, changing the presentation style to Full Screen.

---

So I ended up implementing a compact solution - some will say that it's not OOP without the protocol, and I agree - but in the scope of this app, it solves the problem in the context of a simple present/dismiss construct.

In the presenting vc, I added this code.

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailView") as! DetailViewController
vc.masterVC = self
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The declared a function in the masterVC to be called when the modal dismisses i.e.:

```
func calledWhenModalDismisses() {
   // Do This
}
```

In the modal DetailView that pops up, I just create a member pointing to the master:

```
var masterVC: MasterViewController?
```

And then in my detail dismissal function, I can call back to the function I created in the MasterVC.

```
masterVC?.calledWhenModalDismisses()
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Again, not a truly OOP solution (without the protocol) but I'm sure this will help someone with a simple compact solution to a simple master/detail issue when the presenting vc needs to be alerted as the detail vc is being dismissed. Apple should actually have a delegate function to handle this when a vc comes into "focus" but they do not.